# How to draw text using only OpenGL methods?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics

I don't have the option to use but OpenGL methods (that is `glxxx()` methods). I need to draw text using gl methods only. After reading the red book, I understand that it is possible only through the `glBitmap()` method. If this is the only possible way, then can any one help me with the pixel array information for all the characters. Is there is any other way to draw text?

Answer (score 102):

## Theory

**Why it is hard**

Popular font formats like [TrueType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType) and [OpenType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType) are vector outline formats: they use [Bezier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) to define the boundary of the letter.

[image]

[Image source](http://ingrimayne.com/fonts2/really_old/FontTour/Metamorf.html).

Transforming those formats into arrays of pixels (rasterization) is too specific and out of OpenGL's scope, specially because OpenGl does not have non-straight primitives (e.g. see [Why is there no circle or ellipse primitive in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939072/why-is-there-no-circle-or-ellipse-primitive-in-opengl))

The easiest approach is to first raster fonts ourselves on the CPU, and then give the array of pixels to OpenGL as a texture.

OpenGL then knows how to deal with arrays of pixels through textures very well.

**Texture atlas**

We could raster characters for every frame and re-create the textures, but that is not very efficient, specially if characters have a fixed size.

The more efficient approach is to raster all characters you plan on using and cram them on a single texture.

And then transfer that to the GPU once, and use it texture with custom uv coordinates to choose the right character.

This approach is called a [texture atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas) and it can be used not only for textures but also other repeatedly used textures, like tiles in a 2D game or web UI icons.

The Wikipedia picture of the full texture, which is itself taken from freetype-gl, illustrates this well:

[image]

I suspect that optimizing character placement to the smallest texture problem is an NP-hard problem, see: [What algorithm can be used for packing rectangles of different sizes into the smallest rectangle possible in a fairly optimal way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213394/algorithm-needed-for-packing-rectangles-in-a-fairly-optimal-way)

The same technique is used in web development to transmit several small images (like icons) at once, but there it is called "CSS Sprites": https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ and are used to hide the latency of the network instead of that of the CPU / GPU communication.

**Non-CPU raster methods**

There also exist methods which don't use the CPU raster to textures.

CPU rastering is simple because it uses the GPU as little as possible, but we also start thinking if it would be possible to use the GPU efficiency further.

[This FOSDEM 2014 video](https://youtu.be/LZis03DXWjE?t=886) explains other existing techniques:

- tesselation: convert the font to tiny triangles. The GPU is then really good at drawing triangles. Downsides:

  - generates a bunch of triangles
  - O(n log n) CPU calculation of the triangles
- calculate curves on shaders. A 2005 paper by Blinn-Loop put this method on the map. Downside: complex. See: [Resolution independent cubic bezier drawing on GPU (Blinn/Loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519142/resolution-independent-cubic-bezier-drawing-on-gpu-blinn-loop)
- direct hardware implementations like [OpenVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVG). Downside: not very widely implemented for some reason. See:

  - [OpenGL, OpenVG. Draw text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186811/opengl-openvg-draw-text)
  - [OpenVG implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401422/openvg-implementation)

**Fonts inside of the 3D geometry with perspective**

Rendering fonts inside of the 3D geometry with perspective (compared to an orthogonal HUD) is much more complicated, because perspective could make one part of the character much closer to the screen and larger than the other, making an uniform CPU discretization (e.g. raster, tesselation) look bad on the close part. This is actually an active research topic:

- [What is state-of-the-art for text rendering in OpenGL as of version 4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262951/what-is-state-of-the-art-for-text-rendering-in-opengl-as-of-version-4-1)
- Valve's 20017 signed distance field paper. Previously at: http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf But companies can't not break URLs eventually.

  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1b5hIMqz_wM by
  Martin Donald (2020) is a nice video commenting on it, and it seems to give some more concrete usage advice as well.

[image]

*Distance fields* are one of the popular techniques now.

## Implementations

The examples that follow were all tested on Ubuntu 15.10.

Because this is a complex problem as discussed previously, most examples are large, and would blow up the 30k char limit of this answer, so just clone the respective Git repositories to compile.

They are all fully open source however, so you can just RTFS.

**FreeType solutions**

[FreeType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeType) looks like the dominant open source font rasterization library, so it would allow us to use TrueType and OpenType fonts, making it the most elegant solution.

- https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl

  Was a set of examples  OpenGL and freetype, but is more or less evolving into a library that does it and exposes a decent API.

  In any case, it should already be possible to integrate it on your project by copy pasting some source code.

  It provides both texture atlas and distance field techniques out of the box.

  Demos under: https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl/tree/master/demos

  Does not have a Debian package, and it a pain to compile on Ubuntu 15.10: https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl/issues/82#issuecomment-216025527 (packaging issues, some upstream), but it got better as of 16.10.

  Does not have a nice installation method: https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl/issues/115

  Generates beautiful outputs like this demo:

  [image]
- libdgx https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/1.9.2/extensions/gdx-freetype

Examples / tutorials:

- a NEHE tutorial: [http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/freetype_fonts_in_opengl/24001/](https://web.archive.org/web/20190226103837/http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/freetype_fonts_in_opengl/24001/)
- http://learnopengl.com/#!In-Practice/Text-Rendering mentions it, but I could not find runnable source code
- SO questions:

  - [OpenGL font rendering using Freetype2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271331/opengl-font-rendering-using-freetype2)
  - [Text not rendering correctly - OpenGL using FreeType2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430811/text-not-rendering-correctly-opengl-using-freetype2)

**Other font rasterizers**

Those seem less good than FreeType, but may be more lightweight:

- https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_truetype.h
- http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/

**Anton's OpenGL 4 Tutorials example 26 "Bitmap fonts"**

- tutorial: http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/
- source: https://github.com/capnramses/antons_opengl_tutorials_book/blob/9a117a649ae4d21d68d2b75af5232021f5957aac/26_bitmap_fonts/main.cpp

The font was created by the author manually and stored in a single `.png` file. Letters are stored in an array form inside the image.

This method is of course not very general, and you would have difficulties with internationalization.

Build with:

```
make -f Makefile.linux64
```

Output preview:

[image]

**opengl-tutorial chapter 11 "2D fonts"**

- tutorial: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-11-2d-text/
- source: https://github.com/opengl-tutorials/ogl/blob/71cad106cefef671907ba7791b28b19fa2cc034d/tutorial11_2d_fonts/tutorial11.cpp

Textures are generated from [DDS files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectDraw_Surface).

The tutorial explains how the DDS files were created, using [CBFG](http://www.codehead.co.uk/cbfg/) and [Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net/index.html).

Output preview:

[image]

For some reason Suzanne is missing for me, but the time counter works fine: https://github.com/opengl-tutorials/ogl/issues/15

**FreeGLUT**

GLUT has `glutStrokeCharacter` and FreeGLUT is open source...
https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/FG_3_0_0/src/fg_font.c#L255

**OpenGLText**

https://github.com/tlorach/OpenGLText

TrueType raster. By NVIDIA employee. Aims for reusability. Haven't tried it yet.

**ARM Mali GLES SDK Sample**

http://malideveloper.arm.com/resources/sample-code/simple-text-rendering/ seems to encode all characters on a PNG, and cut them from there.

**glText**

https://github.com/vallentin/glText

Single header C library, that uses a bitmap font baked into the library.

[image]

**SDL_ttf**

[image]

Source: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/d36527fe4977bb9ef4b885b1ec92bd0cd3444a98/sdl/ttf.c

Lives in a separate tree to SDL, and integrates easily.

Does not provide a texture atlas implementation however, so performance will be limited: [How to render fonts and text with SDL2 efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064904/rendering-fonts-and-text-with-sdl2-efficiently)

**Related threads**

- [How to do OpenGL live text-rendering for a GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071621/opengl-live-text-rendering)
- [Text/font rendering in OpenGLES 2 (iOS - CoreText?) - options and best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557535/text-font-rendering-in-opengles-2-ios-coretext-options-and-best-practice)

Answer (score 9):

Drawing text in plain OpenGL isn't a straigth-forward task. You should probably have a look at libraries for doing this (either by using a library or as an example implementation).

Some good starting points could be [GLFont](http://students.cs.byu.edu/~bfish/glfontdl.php), [OpenGL Font Survey](http://www.opengl.org/resources/features/fontsurvey/) and [NeHe Tutorial for Bitmap Fonts (Windows)](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/bitmap_fonts/17002/).

Note that bitmaps are not the only way of achieving text in OpenGL as mentioned in the font survey.

Answer (score 8):

[This article](http://www.opengl.org/resources/features/fontsurvey/) describes how to render text in OpenGL using various techniques.

With only using opengl, there are several ways:

- using glBitmap
- using textures
- using display lists

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Use `glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, myCharString)`.

An example: A STAR WARS SCROLLER.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL\glut.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>

GLfloat UpwardsScrollVelocity = -10.0;
float view=20.0;

char quote[6][80];
int numberOfQuotes=0,i;

//*********************************************
//*  glutIdleFunc(timeTick);                  *
//*********************************************

void timeTick(void)
{
    if (UpwardsScrollVelocity< -600)
        view-=0.000011;
    if(view < 0) {view=20; UpwardsScrollVelocity = -10.0;}
    //  exit(0);
    UpwardsScrollVelocity -= 0.015;
  glutPostRedisplay();

}


//*********************************************
//* printToConsoleWindow()                *
//*********************************************

void printToConsoleWindow()
{
    int l,lenghOfQuote, i;

    for(  l=0;l<numberOfQuotes;l++)
    {
        lenghOfQuote = (int)strlen(quote[l]);

        for (i = 0; i < lenghOfQuote; i++)
        {
          //cout<<quote[l][i];
        }
          //out<<endl;
    }

}

//*********************************************
//* RenderToDisplay()                       *
//*********************************************

void RenderToDisplay()
{
    int l,lenghOfQuote, i;

    glTranslatef(0.0, -100, UpwardsScrollVelocity);
    glRotatef(-20, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glScalef(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);



    for(  l=0;l<numberOfQuotes;l++)
    {
        lenghOfQuote = (int)strlen(quote[l]);
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-(lenghOfQuote*37), -(l*200), 0.0);
        for (i = 0; i < lenghOfQuote; i++)
        {
            glColor3f((UpwardsScrollVelocity/10)+300+(l*10),(UpwardsScrollVelocity/10)+300+(l*10),0.0);
            glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, quote[l][i]);
        }
        glPopMatrix();
    }

}
//*********************************************
//* glutDisplayFunc(myDisplayFunction);       *
//*********************************************

void myDisplayFunction(void)
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluLookAt(0.0, 30.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  RenderToDisplay();
  glutSwapBuffers();
}
//*********************************************
//* glutReshapeFunc(reshape);               *
//*********************************************

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
  glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluPerspective(60, 1.0, 1.0, 3200);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

//*********************************************
//* int main()                                *
//*********************************************


int main()
{
    strcpy(quote[0],"Luke, I am your father!.");
    strcpy(quote[1],"Obi-Wan has taught you well. ");
    strcpy(quote[2],"The force is strong with this one. ");
    strcpy(quote[3],"Alert all commands. Calculate every possible destination along their last known trajectory. ");
    strcpy(quote[4],"The force is with you, young Skywalker, but you are not a Jedi yet.");
    numberOfQuotes=5;

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 400);
    glutCreateWindow("StarWars scroller");
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glLineWidth(3);

    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplayFunction);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(timeTick);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: glutStrokeCharacter is not a opengl function

Comment: it fits in glxxx() OP requirement though :)

Comment: Here's the code modified to work on Ubuntu (glutInit, includes): https://gist.github.com/tgandor/3963f112324030a2c833

Comment: You have a buffer overflow in your fourth quote !

Comment: Seems you are correct. "Alert all commands. Calculate every possible destination along their last known trajectory. " is a 92-byte string, but only 80 bytes have been allocated.

Answer (score 4):

Load an image with characters as texture and draw the part of that texture depending on what character you want. You can create that texture using a paint program, hardcode it or use a window component to draw to an image and retrieve that image for an exact copy of system fonts.

No need to use Glut or any other extension, just basic OpenGL operability. It gets the job done, not to mention that its been done like this for decades by professional programmers in very succesfull games and other applications.

Comment: There are even programs that you can use to generate the image texture for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best solution for drawing text in OpenGL is texture fonts, I work with them for a long time. They are flexible, fast and nice looking (with some rear exceptions). I use special program for converting font files (.ttf for example) to texture, which is saved to file of some internal "font" format (I've developed format and program based on http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Font_System though my version went rather far from the original supporting Unicode and so on). When starting the main app, fonts are loaded from this "internal" format. Look link above for more information.

With such approach the main app doesn't use any special libraries like FreeType, which is undesirable for me also. Text is being drawn using standard OpenGL functions.

Comment: If I may add something to this already good answer, pay attention to the optmization of any font rendering system since it may impact the performances of your engine on very limited HW resources such as mobile devices.