# OpenGL, OpenVG. Draw text?

Tags: text, opengl-es, draw, openvg

There are enough "examples" but all of them represent parts of strange code.

The best code I found is:

[link](http://read.pudn.com/downloads171/sourcecode/others/793972/FontTest/main.cpp__.htm)

but I can't even run it because it has variables and constants with missed declaration.

Can anybody post a full workable example?

Comment: opengl no openvg question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847899/how-to-draw-text-using-only-opengl-methods/36065835#36065835