# How to render text in modern OpenGL with GLSL

Tags: opengl, fonts, glsl, shader, lwjgl

I want to render text in LWJGL by using modern OpenGL (rendering with VBO and shader) but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw text using only OpenGL methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847899/how-to-draw-text-using-only-opengl-methods)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is an approach:

- Create a texture containing all your characters, rasterized at a certain size.
- For each character, store the location of the patch of the texture containing the character

```java
class CharCoords {
    public int x, y, width, height;
}
```

- Upload to the GPU a 2D square geometry with vertices `(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)`
- The vertex shader could look as follows

```glsl
#version 120

uniform mat4 PVMmat;        // The projection-view-model matrix
uniform vec4 charCoords;    // The CharCoord struct for the character you are rendering, {x, y, w, h}
uniform float texSize;      // The size of the texture which contains the rasterized characters (assuming it is square)
uniform vec2 offset;        // The offset at which to paint, w.r.t the first character

attribute vec2 vertex;

varying vec2 tc;

void main(){
    // Transform from absolute texture coordinates to normalized texture coordinates
    // This works because the rectangle spans [0,1] x [0,1]
    // Depending on where the origin lies in your texture (i.e. topleft or bottom left corner), you need to replace "1. - vertex.y" with just "vertex.y"
    tc = (charCoords.xy + charCoords.zw * vec2(vertex.x, 1. - vertex.y)) / texSize;

    // Map the vertices of the unit square to a rectangle with correct aspect ratio and positioned at the correct offset
    float x = (charCoords[2] * vertex.x + offset.x) / charCoords[3];
    float y = vertex.y + offset.y / charCoords[3];

    // Apply the model, view and projection transformations
    gl_Position = PVMmat * vec4(x, y, 0., 1.);
}
```

- The fragment shader is trivial:

```glsl
#version 120

uniform vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D tex;

varying vec2 tc;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = color * texture2D(tex, tc);
}
```

- Your drawing function could then look as follows (note: the code is using a shader class with some convenience methods, but the idea should be clear):

```java
public void drawString(Matrix4f PVMmat, String text, Color color, HAlign halign, VAlign valign) {
    Vector2f offset = new Vector2f();

    // Font alignment
    if(halign == HAlign.Center){
        offset.x = -(int) (0.5f * getWidth(text));
    }else if(halign == HAlign.Right){
        offset.x = -getWidth(text);
    }
    if(valign == VAlign.Middle){
        offset.y = -(int) (0.5f * getHeight());
    }else if(valign == VAlign.Top){
        offset.y = -getHeight();
    }

    m_shader.bind();        
    m_shader.setAttributeBuffer("vertex", m_vertexBuffer, 2);
    m_shader.setUniformMatrix("PVMmat", PVMmat);
    m_shader.setUniformVector("color", color);
    m_shader.setUniformScalar("texSize", (float)m_textureSize);
    m_shader.setTexture("tex", m_fontTexture, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_model.getIndexBuffer());
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); ++i) {
        CharCoords coo = m_charMap.get(text.charAt(i));
        m_shader.setUniformVector("charCoords", new Vector4f(coo.x, coo.y, coo.width, coo.height));
        m_shader.setUniformVector("offset", offset);
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, m_indexCount, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        offset.x += coo.width;
    }
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    m_shader.unbind();
}
```

where the functions `getHeigth` and `getWidth` are:

```java
public int getWidth(String text) {
    int totalwidth = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        CharCoords coo = m_charMap.get(text.charAt(i));
        totalwidth += coo.width;
    }
    return totalwidth;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return m_fontMetrics.getHeight();
}
```

- Note: to set the scale and position of your text, modify the model matrix accordingly.

Comment: But I think, that this would be very slow because I have to change the uniforms for every char twice.

Comment: Keep in mind that the fixed-function pipeline way of drawing text sends vertex and texture coordinates to the GPU for each character you draw, so it is already definitely faster than that approach. But I suggest give it a try and see if performance is adequate, otherwise optimize as necessary. Here it performs well enough.