# How to get an int as input and project a double as output in an OpenGL C++ program?

Tags: c++, opengl, io

I'm developing a OpenGL application in C++ however I require the user to input an `int` and the project to output a `double` plus some text. What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

There's no text input function in OpenGL.  You'll have to use an API on top of openGL, for example manage the keyboard entry with the basic [GLUT keyboard functions](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/keyboard/).

For the output, you have to draw it as part of your graphic output as explained in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847899/opengl-how-to-draw-text-using-only-opengl-methods).

Of course you don't need to reinvent the wheel from scratch and may consider more elaborate API than Glut, as [discussed here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/651198-how-to-get-user-writing-input-string-in-opengl/).

***Edit:*** Just seen today this [tweet from Evan Todd](https://twitter.com/et1337/status/627713349581602816)  with a link to his 160 lines of C++ implementation of in-game console on github.  It's based on OpenGL/glfw. His approach could interest you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your job can be split into two part

1. Taking `integer` input from user
2. Show `double + extra text` it on your window

obviously second part is the easy part, use `glutStrokeCharacter` to show your `double + text` referred [here](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node78.html)

The first part is little bit tricker, you can make a TextEdit like widget using the `glutStrokeCharacter` & `glutKeyboardFunc`. The job of the TextEdit will to show the user original `int` input. just register the keyboard using `glutKeyboardFunc` & on the call back draw the original int inside the TextEdit widget.

`glutKeyboardFunc` is referrence here [here](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node49.html)

suggestion, draw a nice rectangle just behind the TextEdit's to make it seems actual user input :). Happy coding

Comment: OP never said anything about GLUT.

Comment: OP never said anything about 'NO GLUT' too.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this actually which does exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for all the responses.

https://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2008/08/29/console-window-win32-app/

Comment: how does that relates to openGL ? :P Oh I get it, you needed console along with opengl window :). As far As i know every IDE allow having the console opened and at same time opengl window (and also the final executable get the same, you need to explicitly deploy your code as "console application")